# Perceived Areas of Hindu God's Position

Tags: vishnu, shiva, vedas, mahabharata, scripture

Lord Shiva - Kailash Parvat, Himalayas, Snow

Lord Vishnu - Resting on Sheshnaag above Ocean Water

Lord Brahma - Resting on Lotus Flower, Air (It may be correct or not)

Any ideas? Any connection to the God Nature or Personality Traits or any other reasoning.

Comment: could you clarify what the question is? do you want to know what is the connection between God and nature? Thanks